# How to do daily backup?

Tags: windows, backup

Sorry for the dumb question, but I have a Windows XP box we use for a 'server' in the LAN network to store various important files. We have 2 hard drives (1 TB each) and want to use the second one for a daily backup, just in case the first one fails. I'm thinking of running a scheduled batch file, something like this:

```
for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=/ " %%d in ("%date%") do set BackupDir=e:\%%e-%%f-%%g\
mkdir %BackupDir%
xcopy /s /-y C:\SourceSafe %BackupDir%
```

The files are 4 GB in total so it'll take more than half a year before the hard disk runs out of space.

I am wondering if there are potential problems with this way. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Give a try to [Cobian Backup](http://www.educ.umu.se/~cobian/cobianbackup.htm), it's easy to use and can run as a service in windows.